# Trying to force download of xml file fails in larger files

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

**EDIT**
I solved the issue itself by zipping the XML up and sending it out as `application/zip`. Still, the question remains why it does not work in plain XML.

---

I'm currently trying to let users of our website download an xml-file with so called "late responses", in case the automatic processing fails and their requests need to be looked at by a person. The site is basically just a simple GUI over a soap-webservice for the non-technical-inclined, but thats not that important for the issue.

When there are late responses, the site shows the total number and offers to download them, I'm currently archieving this via

```
// XML-content is aggregated and written to response outputstream
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE);
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "ergebnisprot_" + new DateTime().toString("ddMMyyyyHHmmSS") + ".xml");
response.flushBuffer();
```

This works well if only about one to five responses are aggregated. The browser gets a download-popup and everything goes the way it is supposed to go.

But with larger files, depending on the individual size, but usually from about 10 responses upward, this popup does not appear. Instead, the browser renders the xml itself, which is undesirable, since it's considered of no use to the user to not have the file on his harddrive, or to have to then copy it himself into a file.

Does anyone know why this behaviour happens? Did I miss something in my header configuration?

Comment: I would have guessed that "Content-Disposition" as attachment would do the trick. But it doesn't?
A somewhat dirty approach would be to set the content type to application/octet-stream.

Comment: Yeah thats what I thought, but somehow it doesn't, at least not reliably. I will give the octet-stream a try, but honestly I doubt it. I fear that the XML-content, something the browser can work with, effs it up somehow.